# Yasm compiling 64 bit code with intel syntax

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, yasm

I have this file:

```
.code64
pop %rbx
```

that compiles nicely with yasm with the following directive:

```
yasm.exe asm.asm -o asm.bin -m amd64 --parser=gas
```

my question is: is there any way to use nasm parser to compile 64 bit code by using intel syntax? I don't really like AT&T syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [yasm manual about the BITS directive](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/nasm-directives.html#nasm-directive-bits).

```
bits 64
pop rbx
```

```
yasm.exe asm.asm -o asm.bin -m amd64
```