# Yasm with 64-bit instructions

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, yasm

I'm trying to assemble some assembly source code for x86_64 written in Intel syntax that uses **64-bit registers**.  I use the following command line flags:

```
yasm foo.asm -a x86 -m amd64
```

I keep getting errors like:

```
warning: `rbp' is a register in 64-bit mode
foo.asm:23: error: undefined symbol `rbp' (first use)
```

So, I've seen a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217080/yasm-compiling-64-bit-code-with-intel-syntax) on stackoverflow, as well as [numerous resources](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/yasm/yasm_arch.7.en.html) on the web that indicate that this problem can be solved by specifying the "BITS" directive, specifically like:

```
BITS 64
```

The problem is, it's unclear to me what that even means.  I don't understand what a "directive" is.  It seems to be something you need to specify in the assembly code itself.  But in this case, I don't control the code, so I'm just trying to find a command line flag to assemble it.

Is there a way to specify the `BITS` directive in a command line flag that I can pass to yasm?

Comment: `bits 64` simply says to encode the instructions assuming the code will be running in a 64-bit mode.

Comment: `-m amd64` as per the [manual](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/running-arch.html).

Comment: @Jester `-m amd64` controls the object file format, the OP already included it. However, I don't see why they can't simply add `BITS 64` and the source to a temporary file.

Comment: @Jester : He is already using `-m amd64` according to the question. I don't know if this is an OSDev question or not, but I assume the reason is that you aren't specifying a `-f` option and it is defaulting to `-fbin` which will assume `bits 16` by default

Comment: No idea how I missed the `-m amd64` in the question, I stopped reading at `-a x86` :D

Comment: Use `-felf64` make 64-bit ELF object files where BITS 64 is the default.  Avoid BITS if possible, because it doesn't change the object file format, i.e. it will let you assemble 64-bit machine code into an executable that will be run in 32-bit mode.  (Although to link it you'd have to use `gcc -m32` or something.  Usually the problem is the other way around when people use `.code32` in gas syntax, where the default is the native mode for the platform, e.g. x86-64).

Comment: That is assuming he wants to make an elf executable. I don't know if it was his intention to not use the `-f` option (defaulting to `-f bin`. If this was for an OSDev project then it would make sense but there really isn't enough to know for certain how the code is being used with what is presented. `-felf64` also may make an assumption that he isn't on something like MacOS where they might be using macho64 or Win64 on Windows.

Comment: Are we sure that yasm actually supports intel syntax?  I don't see anything in their docs that says so.  The `bits` directive only talks about what code it is going to *generate*, not how it interprets the source.  If yasm is interpreting intel syntax as at&t, then the errors above make perfect sense.

Answer (score 4):

Use `-felf64` to assemble x86-64 code into a 64-bit ELF `.o`.

If you're making a flat binary (not a `.o` or `.obj`) use `BITS 64` at the top of your file.  Otherwise avoid it, you normally don't want to put 64-bit machine code into a 32-bit `.o`; a build-time error is better.

---

Despite the documentation [in the manual](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/running-arch.html), YASM's `-a x86 -m amd64` options *don't* override the default for **the default `-fbin` flat binary output format, which is to assemble assuming the code will be executed in 16-bit mode.  (Exactly like NASM).**

Using `-m x86` *does* prevent `-felf64`, or `BITS 64` inside a file, from working.  It's part of YASM's CPU-feature limits support, that can help stop you from accidentally using ISA features not supported by the target CPU.  (e.g. `CPU Conroe AMD` enables everything up to SSSE3, and AMD64 instructions like `syscall`, while disabling SSE4 and AVX.  The default is no limits.)

---

`BITS 16` is the default mode with `-fbin`.

**The assembler has to know what mode the CPU is expected to execute your code in.**  For example, `mov eax,ecx` is `89 C8` in 32-bit mode, but `66 89 C8` in 16-bit mode (operand-size override prefix and then the same opcode + modrm as for 32-bit mode).

64-bit operand-size and address-size, and 64-bit registers in general, are only encodeable in 64-bit mode, hence the error when trying to assemble code using `rbp` when the assembler is making code that will execute in 16-bit mode.

A bootloader that starts in 16-bit mode might switch to 32 and/or 64-bit mode, so you'd need a `BITS 32` or `BITS 64` directive in front of the jump target for the `jmp far` that switches to 32-bit or 64-bit mode.

*This* is the normal use-case for a BITS directive.  Unfortunately, like NASM, there doesn't seem to be a command-line option that will assemble a flat binary in your choice of mode.  It would be cool if you could put `inc eax` into a file and get `66 40`, `40`, or `FF C0` without editing the file, just using command-line options, but we can't.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly, your question is:
How to "activate" 64-bit mode??

It's really simple.

If your code is:

```
mov rax, [rbp - 2]
mov rbx, rax
syscall  ;just to call some or for end of code
```

Then change it to:

```
bits 64

mov rax, [rbp - 2]
mov rbx, rax
syscall  ;just to call some or for end of code
```

Simply put, **put the "bits 64" in the start of your code!**

Comment: And those error that you get are because: 1.) the rbp is 64 and normally it is in 16-32. 2.) the second error comes because the warning from the first error because it could't make the rbp